# The Sum $\sum^\infty_{i=k}\frac{1}{i!(i)(i-1)...(i-k+1)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

$\def \ei{\operatorname{Ei}}$

> Evaluate $$\sum^\infty_{i=k}\frac{1}{i!(i)(i-1)...(i-k+1)}$$

If we look at:
$$P_k(x)=\sum^\infty_{i=k}\frac{x^i}{i!(i)(i-1)...(i-k+1)}$$
so:
$$P_k^{(k)}(x)=\sum^\infty_{i=k}\frac{x^{i-k}}{i!}=\frac{e^x-\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}\frac{x^{i}}{i!}}{x^k}$$
The way the sum is structured causes
$$P^{(m)}_k(0)=0$$
so,
$$P_k(1)=\int_0^1\int_0^{x_{k-1}}...\int^{x_1}_0\frac{e^x-\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}\frac{x^{i}}{i!}}{x^k}dx_1dx_2...dx_{k-1}$$
(I'm not very sure of this integral and it's correctness)
In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254755/the-integral-int-limits-01-fracex-sumn-1-i-0-fracxiixnd/4255405#4255405)
An answer gave the idea of using integration by parts to solve the first integral, but I didn't manage to generalize it.
here is a table of single cases generously provided by wolfram alpha:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
n & \text{The Intergral} \\ \hline
0 & e \\ \hline
1 & \ei(1)-\gamma \\ \hline
2 & 3-e \\ \hline
3 & \frac{1}{4}(\gamma-\ei(1)-4+2e) \\ \hline
4 & \frac{1}{108}(12\ei(1)-12\gamma+17-12e) \\ \hline
5 & \frac{1}{1152}(30\gamma-30\ei(1)+7+12e) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Here is your partial [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254755/the-integral-int-limits-01-fracex-sumn-1-i-0-fracxiixnd/4254807#4254807)

Comment: I would rewrite the denominator as $(i-k+1)!\cdot i$. The summation is then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(n+k-1)}$. Wolfram solved it: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+1%2F%28n%21%28n%2Br%29%29

Answer (score 2):

Using Pochhammer symbols
$$\prod_{n=0}^{k-1} (i+n)=i \,(i+1)_{k-1}$$
$$f(k)=\sum^\infty_{i=k}\frac{1}{i!\,i\, (i+1)_{k-1}}=\frac{\, _2F_2(1,k;2 k,k+1;1)}{k\, k! \,(k+1)_{k-1}}$$

We have
$$f(k)=\frac {a_k}{b_k}-2\frac {c_k}{k!} e+\frac{\text{Ei}(1)-\gamma }{(k-1)!}$$ where the $(a_k,b_k,c_k)$ are respectively the sequences
$$\{0,3,33,43,74491,1311893,757144583,82933253839,467118744066553\}$$
$$\{1,2,16,27,69120,1728000,1306368000,176033088000,1171676233728000\}$$
$$\{0,1,3,8,25,102,539,3496,26613,231170\}$$

The $c_k$ correspond to sequence $A051403$ is $OEIS$. I did not find in $OEIS$ anything related to the $a_k$ or $b_k$